# How to install mosek for cvxpy?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, cvxpy, mosek

Previously I used command `conda install -c mosek mosek` to install mosek(my IDE is VS Code and use anaconda environment). After I installed it, I ran a program for a convex optimization problem, and one line of code was(because I want to choose mosek as solver):

```
prob.solve(solver=cp.MOSEK)
```

then an error pops up:

> cvxpy.error.SolverError: The solver MOSEK is not installed.

BUT I have MOSEK installed. I used the following piece of code to detect:

```
import cvxpy as cp

print(cp.installed_solvers())
```

the result is:

```
['ECOS', 'ECOS_BB', 'OSQP', 'SCIPY', 'SCS']
```

Why does this happen?

I used the `conda list` command to check if I have mosek installed:

[image: Related picture]

But I did install it!

How can I solve it?

---

Besides, every time I run the program it pops up this error:

> Encountered unexpected exception importing solver MOSEK:
> ImportError('DLL load failed while importing _msk: 找不到指定的模块。')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tested that your conda installed Mosek can be used outside Cvxpy i.e. directly from Python.

Comment: When I try to use the command ‘import mosek’, an error pops up: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _msk:

Comment: @Lancdorr It is as if something didn't install correctly. What is your operating system? Can you try reinstalling mosek?

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Windows 11, I have uninstalled and reinstalled MOSEK several times. Should I download the full distribution?

Comment: If you are sure "import mosek" tries to import mosek from your conda installation, and not from some older/different installation that you might have lying around in another place on your disk, then contact support@mosek.com with a complete log output from conda install and we will discuss it there. You can also try to install with pip and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek I just read the official documentation, which mentioned that MOSEK needs to set up LICENSE to run. And I haven't set it yet, could that be the reason?

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek I have solved the license problem, but I still get this error when I run the program: Encountered unexpected exception importing solver GLPK and Encountered unexpected exception importing solver GLPK_MI

Comment: The license should not come up so early as to prevent loading the module. About GLPK solver I cannot help much unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your needed module is installed in the current selected environment. Open an **new integrated** Terminal and run `conda list mosek`, check if its location is the one shown in status bar:

[image]